# Como converter um texto para html laravel

Tags: php, laravel

No meu banco de dados estou salvando o corpo de uma notícia, e ela está vindo com tag´s em html, como eu faço pra mostrar esse texto sem as tag´s que está sendo salva no banco de dados

Answer (score 3):

Ao invés de usar o interpolador padrão, adicione dois sinais de exclamação (!!) depois de abrir as chaves e antes de fechar.

```
{!! $textoHtml !!}
```

Veja mais na [documentação do Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#displaying-data)